# Unable to import a module from a sub-package into another sub-package

Tags: python-3.x

I am unable to import module from a different package.

The module ***connection.py*** is in a package ***instance_connector*** and the module ***record_parameter.py*** is in a different package called ***instance_parameters***.

Both of these packages are the sub-packages of a package called ***snowflake***.

Here is the tree diagram of directory structure.

```
snowflake
├── __init__.py
├── instance_connector
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── connection.py
└── instance_parameters
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── load_parameters.py
    ├── modals.py
    └── record_parameters.py
```

I am trying to import a module ***connection.py*** into module ***record_parameter.py*** like this -

***record_parameter.py***

```
from snowfake.instance_connector.connection import SnowflakeConnector
```

When I run this file via terminal using command `python record_parameter.py` it returns me an error stated below -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "record_parameters.py", line 3, in <module>
    from snowflake.instance_connector.connection import SnowflakeConnector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake.instance_connector'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried appending the path which leads to the file `connection.py` using the `sys` module in `record_parameters.py`?

```
import sys
sys.path.append(1, 'xyz/snowflake/instance_connector/connection.py')
```